# auto-completion of \eqref

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, texmaker, auto-completion

All references are marked with

- eq -> equation
- tab -> table
- fig -> figure
- app -> appendix
- sec -> section
- chp -> chapter

So a reference would look like

```
\label{eq:NT_LoM}
\label{sec:intro}
```

for Newton's law of motion, and the introduction section.

I have been looking around for a way to sort my reference so that if I write `\eqref` the auto-completion only give me options to chose between references with 'eq' in. And the same for the other pre-fixes.

I have tried to use the `\newcommand` function, but this does not give me the auto-completion options.

```
\newcommand{\tabref}[1]{\ref{#1}
```

But the auto-completion doesn't seem to work.

Comment: With other words: If the label refers to a table, the reference should show `Table 1.1` etc automatically? `cleveref` package and `\cref` ?

Comment: Never heard of that one, need to look it up, but that does what I'm looking for/making?

Comment: I'll show an example in a few minutes. It won't expand however your label prefix in a direct way. The appendix `app` could be difficult, actually.

Comment: @Mikkel Are you talking about the *text editor's* autocompletion? I don't think Texmaker can do it out of the box, so this should probably be a feature request for the program's developers.

Comment: @egreg  that was what I was hoping for, but it seems that it is to much to ask for..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows the application of `cleveref` for the standard counters and the difference between `\cref` and `\Cref` -- the later is used for uppercase completion of the counter name.

The completion names can be specified with the commands `\crefname` and `\Crefname` (see the documentation please)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First} \label{chp:somechapter}

\section{first section} \label{sec:somesection}

\begin{equation}
E=mc^2 \label{eq:einstein}
\end{equation}

\begin{table}
\caption{dummytable} \label{tab:dummytable}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
\caption{dummyfigure} \label{fig:dummyfigure}
\end{figure}

In \cref{eq:einstein}, \cref{tab:dummytable} and \Cref{fig:dummyfigure} from \cref{chp:somechapter} and \cref{sec:somesection} we see that... but in \Cref{app:chapter1}

\appendix
\chapter{First appendix chapter} \label{app:chapter1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't download the cleveref.sty  would it be possible for you to include a output example?

Comment: @Mikkel: I was just doing it ;-)

Comment: -1 to university network restrictions! just needed another download source. 

On topic, that is exactly what I was looking for!. A wounder that I never meet it before ... Thanks Christian

Comment: @Mikkel: No problem at all. Happy TeXing then! `cleveref` is a standard nowadays, I would say, it should be on any TeX distribution. Make sure to include it after `hyperref`

Comment: Just noticed that i does not have the auto-completion, functionality, but as egreg pointed out, that is most likely a functionality of the editor. 

With the cleveref I still get most of the functionality I was looking for

Comment: @Mikkel: I never claimed that it is auto-completion. I don't use editors which provide auto-completion -- that's a feature I don't need.

Comment: Never said you did, not my intention to imply that.  My original hope was to have the functionality of the cleveref with auto-completion. But as this is not possible (at least not in TM), then cleveref gives me what I want. 

Currently have more than 400 labels of different types, thus the autocompletion would be nice as I can not remember them all ;)

Comment: How to refer theorem/Propositions/lemmas ?  Any help please